# WinForms: how to retrieve the system colors for highlighted buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, systemcolors

When writing WinForms desktop applications (VB or C#), how can I retrieve/mimic the current system colors scheme for buttons (i.e. fill and border colors when static and ESPECIALLY when highlighted)?
For example, on my Windows 10 with (Aero?) theme, buttons look like this:

[image]

I tried SystemColors constants but couldn't replicate the colors in the above image.

Comment: These are visual styles theme colors, drawn with VisualStyleRenderer.DrawBackground().  You are probably looking for its GetColor() method.

Comment: That's weird. I can't access most properties and methods! When I type `VisualStyles.VisualStyleRenderer.` I get a list of "Equals", "IsElementDefined" and "ReferenceEquals" methods and "IsSupported" property...

Comment: It is not a static method, use the `new` keyword to create the object.

Comment: No cigar. Tried all possible combinations of elements and color properties. The colors I see and want are not there...

Comment: Well, it is rocket science.  I think the underlying problem is that the background often uses a gradient brush.  Consider drawing into a small bitmap and using GetPixel().  But certainly best to just get it over with and use DrawBackground().